# How to stop grep after matching

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

In Windows, I would have done a search for finding a folders name using findsr Similarly, I want to get a specific folder using `grep`

In windows, I'm using  `svnlook tree -t [repos_path] | findstr (13\.9\.[0-9]+\/)`

In Ec2 Maiche (Linux) `svnlook tree /var/www/svn/ILS | grep -Eo  '(13\.9\.[0-9]+\/)'`
and I got the repos that I need

- 13.9.4/
- 13.9.5/
- 13.9.6/
- 13.9.7/

my problem is the grep line in Linux doesn't want to stop (exit) it's still running.

[image]

how could I stop it after matching?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the `-m`: maximal number of counts. After the specified number of matching lines, grep will stop.

Comment: I want -m (automatically) will stop because i dnt know how  many folders to be matched

Comment: I don't understand. How many lines of output do you want to get?

Comment: When ’grep‘ match all the string  stop . my problem as you can see in the picture  i got all folders name and grep still searching.

Comment: @MokiNex But grep can't know if there will be more matches or not until it has looked at every line of input.

Comment: But why it takes to long  more then 5min and with findstr less then second ? It may the regex is wrong?

Comment: Sounds more like you forgot to do what it says in the answer. `grep -m 1  -Eo  '13\.9\.[0-9]+/'` should finish as soon as it finds the first match. (I took out some unnecessary chaff from your regex.)

Comment: how can match the last repo 13.9.7/ instead of 13.9.4/

Answer (score 0):

After `^Z` the `svnlook` is paused. You kan kill (`^C`) the program, send it to the background (`bg`) or continue (`fg`).
When you want to interrupt you can use `^C` or start the `grep` with a `-m` option.

Comment: do you know to get a specific folder and his subfolder using grep or similar?

Comment: Does `svnlook tree /var/www/svn/ILS | grep -E '(13\.9\.[0-9]+\/)'` show the folder?
You can use `sed` for selecting different substrings in these lines.

Comment: it takes me too long to get repository names! how can I avoid that? `svnlook tree  /var/www/svn/ILS --full-paths | grep -E 'RC/13\.9\.[0-9]/$'`

Comment: The `grep -m` option of `head -100` might help, but you should focus on a way to make your `svnlook` faster. I can't help you here, I don't know the `svn` tools and options.